# Moodle Plugin to register new users using Paypal?

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to implement a plugin in Moodle where new users are registered using Paypal.
And the registration for the new users will require paypal payment to complete registration. 
If anybody can help me with any example, code, plugin, or any link, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

PayPal enrollment is included as part of Moodle's core code, so you just need to enable and then configure it. Documentation is [here](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Paypal_enrolment). This covers enrollment in a specific course, rather than new user signup as typically people want to charge different amounts for different courses, rather than a flat rate for access to everything.

There is no existing PayPal authentication plugin to make it so that a user must pay to register on the site, but if you want to make one the developer docs are [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins).

Comment: Does that mean, the only way to integration PayPal at the time of Registration is "Custom Development"?